# Object definition in C# to comply with JSON definition

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have this JSON definition:

```
{
    "id": 1400,
    "types": {
        "type one": {
           "url": "http://www.example.com",
           "desc": "type one desc"
        },
        "type two": {
            "url": "http://www.example.com",
            "desc": "type two desc"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to create a C# class that when serialized produces the JSON above.

The problem I'm having is with "type one" and "type two". If my class looks like this:

```
public class mytypes{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<mytype> types { get; set; }
}
```

where mytype is:

```
public class mytype {

    public string url { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}
```

Data is coming from a database and this generates an array of "types", not one "types" object with objects inside it that have a description as the definition (type one, type two).

How can I change my class to generate "type one" and "type two" inside of "types", and not an array?

Comment: Is there an unknown number of "types" in the list? If it's always the same number, you can do the JSON like you said, but if it's really a list object, LIST will be where it says "types" in your JSON and everything will be pushed a level down. I did not find this helpful, and ended up manually serializing.

Comment: Yes, the number is unknown since it comes from a database and may change at any time. I was trying to avoid having to manually serialize it if at all possible.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid that too, but the automated serialization can't do anything special. It MUST show you the entire hierarchy, so it has to include the list as an object, which contains other objects. The Dictionary as suggested below will be the same way.

Comment: Garath's example below works great. If you supply the keys to the dicitonary, then it uses those to create "type one", "type two", and so forth.

Comment: I would consider that partial manual serialization.

Comment: I agree, but partial is still better than full :-)

Comment: Yes, it's a little better, but when you're changing your objects, it can become a maintenance hassle. With auto-generation, when the object changes, I think all you need is to recompile, and if it's an ASP.Net web site that will happen automagically on your server when you publish new object files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
public List<mytype> types { get; set; }
```

you have to use `Dictionary` so the property will be:

```
public Dictionary<string,mytype> types { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Garath. The only piece I don't understand is how is "type one", "type two" assigned?

Comment: Just add elements to dictionary with proper keys. Liek this: types.Add("type one", new mytype{url="http://cxxxx/", desc="something"});